# WordPress Form E-Mail delivering

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, smtp

I 'm trying to fix a problem here in a wordpress eviremont which I'm also new to. I want to get a form running but it isn't sending emails. Currently I'm using Caldera Forms with the WordPress email system. What I want to do is that everytime somebody applies a form, I want to get a email with the content of the form and the user who applied to the form should get a normal autoresponder email. I think this should work without any email plugin or something else, but I'm not sure. I'm trying to fix a probleme here on a wordpress site which crashed after too many people visited this page. Now, the email system espacially the send and receive a email if somebody applied on a form, is not working anymore.. As mentinoed, I don't think that you need a email plugin to do that. I'm right? 
Further, the emails get hostet by CrazyDomains. If I use the webmailer, I can receive and send emails from the emails on CrazyDomains.

Where could be the problem?

A plugin called Postman SMTP generates a log which also logs the form emails. This log says:
"250 OK" (I shorted the log). So, it means, the email should be send. For no reason, as already written, I do not receive and get emails with the form...
This plugin is connected with GMAIL API. I don't know why and for what that is...

I already deactivated all email plugins and tried different form plugins like Gravity Form or Contact Form. But same result...
How can I figure out whats the problem and how can I solve it?

I would be very happy about help.
Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a Quick config smtp https://www.crazydomains.com.au/help/getting-started-guide-email-hosting/#SDj5xkUTdbsVJ4mL.97.

Maybe email went in the spam section, or you had not configured good the smtp.
You can try to install https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ and configure email sent from wordpress as say the crazydomains guide, so with the port 587 etc.